# Populate Periodic Snapshot Fact Table

Tags: mysql, database, fact-table

[dim_order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nuj6.png)

[dim_date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeM2P.png)

[orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ6wK.png)

[facthistorylevel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tsbs.png)

[example**i want to populate data into facthistorylevel table as example bút i dont know how to do it with mysql. anyone help me**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf6wB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't link to images. Provide all relevant information directly in your question, preferably as editable text